# Analogous event to DocumentComplete in Chromium embedded?

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I needs this event , because the first time I open the page (google maps)  ,and then the event after it loads ( one-off ) would like to call the script for the event.

Comment: Maybe there isn't an exact equivalent.  Have you tried OnLoadingStateChange and OnLoadEnd?  OnLoadEnd seems to be the last significant event when the GuiClient demo loads the google page.

Comment: On `LoadEnd` work perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, try `OnLoadEnd`.

In the GuiClient demo, it seems to be the last significant event when it loads the google page, after numerous others.